# how to determine if a vector filed is a gradient field or a rotation field

Tags: vector-fields

Which of the following is neither a gradient field nor a rotation field?

$$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})= ||\mathbf{r}||^2\mathbf{r}$$

or $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})= \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{i}$$

I know that if the curl is $0$ then it **is** a gradient field however I don't understand how to work that out.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the curl? Where do you get stuck in computing it for $f$?

Comment: @Keshav yes I know what the curl is but what is $\mathbf{r}$?

Comment: $\mathbf r = \langle x,y,z\rangle$ is the "position" vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$f(r) = ||r||^2 \,\vec{r} = ||r||^2 (x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k})$

$curl F = \nabla \times F = ||r||^2 \,\begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ x & y & z\end {vmatrix} = ?$

In second case,

$f(r) = \vec{r} \times \hat{i} = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ x & y & z \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end {vmatrix} = ?
$

Once you get $f(r)$, find its curl just like in the first case.

Comment: $$\nabla\times (r^2\vec r)=\nabla(r^2)\times \vec r+r^2\nabla \times \vec r=0$$